# Search for name in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have `var='smth'` and I need to check if `var` exists in the table 'smtb'

I tried something this, but it does not work:

```
rows=curs.fetchall()
for row in rows:
            if var==row:
                print("Yes")
```

When I print elements of rows, I get some pattern like this:

```
('element',)
```

How can I check whether `var` exists in the table?

Answer (score 2):

*Don't* do this in Python. If you want to search for something in a database table by far the quickest and most efficient way is to do it in SQL. Don't forget to use [bind variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/glossary.htm#CNCPT44447).

Assuming you have a cursor object `curs` it might look something like this (assuming your table is unique on `var`).

```
>>> sql = "select * from my_table where var = :var"
>>> bind_variables = {'var' : 'smth'}
>>>
>>> curs.execute(sql, bind_variables)
[<cx_Oracle.STRING with value None>]
>>> results = curs.fetchall()
>>> results
[('smth',)]
>>> try:
...     var = results[0][0]
...     print ('Yes')
... except IndexError:
...     print ('No')
...
Yes
```

Then if you're looking for something that doesn't exist you get the following.

```
>>> bind_variables = {'var' : 'other'}
>>> results = curs.fetchall()
>>> results
[]
>>> try:
...     var = results[0][0]
...     print ('Yes')
... except IndexError:
...     print ('No')
...
No
```

The actual reason why you don't get what you expect is that cx_Oracle returns a list of tuples as per [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). You're expecting only one column to be returned so you need an access the 0<sup>th</sup> index of the tuple, if you want to do it in the manner you are.

```
>>> rows = [('other',),('smth',)]
>>> var = 'smth'
>>> for row in rows:
...     if var == row[0]:
...         print ('Yes')
...
Yes
```